# How do I create a section (form) for the WordPress plugin setting page (admin panel)?

Tags: php, wordpress, herbert

I am using the [Herbert](http://getherbert.com/) Plugin Framework and am creating a plugin.

Here is the code I am using:

#### panels.php

```
$panel->add([
    'type' => 'panel',
    'as'   => 'mainPanel',
    'title' => 'Plugin',
    'rename' => 'General',
    'slug' => 'plugin-admin-settings',
    'icon' => 'dashicons-chart-area',
    'uses' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controllers\PluginController@createAdminPage'
]);
```

Now PluginController

```
 <?php
    namespace Plugin\Controllers;

    use Herbert\Framework\Models\Option;
    use Herbert\Framework\RedirectResponse;
    use Herbert\Framework\Http;
    use \Google_Client;
    use \Google_Service_Analytics;
    use Plugin\Helper;

    class PluginController {

        public static function createAdminPage()
        {
            $this->option = get_option('pluginAuthenticationSetting');

            //if (!isset($this->option['authenticationCode'])):
            //if (get_option('pluginAuthenticationSetting') == FALSE):

                return view('@Plugin/auth.twig', [
                  'title'   => 'Analytics Reports',
                  'content' => SELF::settings()
                ]);
            //endif;
        }

        public static function settings()
        {
            settings_fields('pluginAuthenticationSetting');
            do_settings_sections('pluginAuthenticationSetting');
            submit_button();
        }

        public static function pageInit()
        {
            wp_register_script(
                'plugin',
                Helper::assetUrl('/jquery/plugin.js'),
                array( 'jquery' )
            );

            wp_localize_script(
               'plugin',
               'ajax_object',
               array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
               'we_value' => 1234 )
            );

            register_setting(
               'pluginAuthenticationSetting',
               'plugin_authorization_setting',
               array( __CLASS__, 'sanitize' )
            );

            add_settings_section(
               'authenticationSection',
               'Authentication Section',
               array( __CLASS__, 'printAuthenticationSection' ),
               'pluginAuthenticationSetting'
            );

            add_settings_field(
               'authenticationCode',
                'Authentication Code',
               array( __CLASS__, 'authenticationCodeCallback' ),
               'apluginAuthenticationSetting',
               'authenticationSection'
            );
        }

        public function sanitization( $input )
        {
            $new_input = array();

            if (isset( $input['authenticationCode']))
                $new_input['authenticationCode'] = sanitize_text_field($input['authenticationCode']);

            return $new_input;
        }

        public static function printAuthenticationSection()
        {
            print 'Enter Your Authentication Code Below:';
        }

        public static function authenticationCodeCallback()
        {

            printf( '<input type="text" id="authentication" name="analyticaAuthenticationSetting[authenticationCode]" value="%s" />', isset( $this->option['authenticationCode'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->option['authenticationCode'] ) : '');
        }
    }
```

Now `pageInit()` needs the `admin_init` hook. If I create a constructor and try like `add_action('admin_init', array(__CLASS__, 'pageInit'));`, it is not working. If I use it in panel creation and call createAdminPage taht is also not working. How it can be done?

It generates no error, and only the submit button is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to focus on where we want to send data.

Answer: To the *administration side* of WordPress, that is, we need to use a **panel** to do the job. When we send data to *client side*, we use a **route**.

Here is the code.

#### Creating a panel

```
$panel->add([
    'type' => 'panel',
    'as'   => 'mainPanel',
    'title' => 'Analytica',
    'rename' => 'General',
    'slug' => 'analytica-admin-settings',
    'icon' => 'dashicons-chart-area',
    'uses' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controllers\AnalyticaController@index',
    'post' => [
        // Sending data to save using post.
        'save' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Controllers\AnalyticaController@save',
        ]
]);
```

#### Controller to display the page and save the data in the database

```
<?php namespace Analytica\Controllers;

    use Herbert\Framework\Models\Option;
    use Herbert\Framework\RedirectResponse;
    use Herbert\Framework\Http;
    use Herbert\Framework\Enqueue;
    use Herbert\Framework\Notifier;
    use \Google_Client;
    use Analytica\Helper;

    class AnalyticaController {
        public function index(){
            // Display the form
        }

        public function save(){
            // Validate and save the data
        }
    }
```

You need to focus on `use Herbert\Framework\Models\Option;`. That means there is an model called **Option** that represents the `wp_options` table.

Now, what are the functions we use here?

We can use the [Laravel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laravel_%28framework%29) Eloquent and Schema here. Now you may understand it; we can do a lot of things here. It is like just we are having some pre-built models and we are working on the same Laravel.

*Note: Forget about hooks for some time. We can still suit a theme, but for most of the cases we do not need a theme.*